# Test for a set of N combinations of elements can be used to calculate the sum of each distinct element

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, ssis, set-theory

I need to have general test to see if I can calculate the sum of the distinct elements using a combination of the elements, where the sum of each combination is known but the individual elements value is not. If you can calculate this distinct sum then the set is valid, if not then the set is invalid. An element will not appear twice in a combination.

To illustrate:

- Set 1: {A+B}, {B,C} is an invalid set
- Set 2: {A}, {B}, {B,C} is a valid set ( {A} + {B,C} = A+B+C )
- Set 3: {A,D}, {B,C,A}, {B,C} is an invalid set
- Set 4: {A,B}, {B,C}, {A,C} is a valid set ( ({A,B}, {B,C}, {A,C})/2 =
  A+B+C )

Would be looking to implement the test via C# or SQL.

Comment: Also if you have a more succinct way to describe this scenario that would be a bonus!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really be helpful.  This looks like a homework-type problem.  Even so, just figuring out how to explain it well is helpful.

Comment: Right now, this is a math problem; not a programming question.  If you figure out the math formula that solves the problem, we can help you write it in C# or SQL.